# Es necesario agregar pacake-lock.json al commit de git?

Tags: git, github, npm, laravel-8

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto laravel 8 y a la hora de clonar el repositorio lo siguiente fue ejecutar composer install y npm install para las dependencias, esto me genero un archivo "package-lock.json", antes de hacer actualizaciones quiero saber si debo o no incluir este archivo en futuros commits disponibles para el equipo.

Comment: https://elabismodenull.wordpress.com/2017/07/07/el-fichero-package-lock-json-tengo-que-versionarlo/  (TLDR; **sí**)

Comment: Los archivos .lock se suelen utilizar para despliegues automáticos. El .lock te asegura que los vendors son exactamente la versión con la que te funciona tu proyecto. Si no lo subes se va a crear cuando el despliegue descargue las librerías necesarias. En principio no es necesario, pero en un futuro lo necesitaras